# Why my setting variable to false in while loop gives me error instead of stopping the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating my first Python game ever, and I tried to do pause/unpause game function. I have created a global `pause` variable which is set to `false` by declaration. But when i press press button assigned to my pause function the programs gives me this error:
`local variable 'pause' referenced before assignment`

Here's `paused()` function assignment to a button:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_p:
    pause = True
    paused()
```

And here's my `paused()` function:

```
def paused():  

while pause:        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                pause = False


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)          
    #gameDisplay.fill(white)   `
```

Comment: indentation matters. yours is off.

Comment: you need to read about scoping - your local variable is not known in other functions

Comment: [short-description-of-the-scoping-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: why not just say `while True:` I don't often find a good reason to convolute a Boolean just because you don't like its name. The function `paused()` should be enough of an indicator of what is going on to not assign a Boolean to a variable.

Comment: You could pass the `pause` variable to the `paused` function, otherwise you're going to have to declare `global pause` within `paused`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pause` is a local variable of your main, so sending it to the function is necessarry. Also, there were some identation errors. Here is the fixed version:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_p:
    pause = True
    paused(pause)

def paused(pause):  

    while pause:        

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                    pause = False


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)          
        #gameDisplay.fill(white)   `
```